# can't print a value from database in a view under codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, variable-assignment

Here is my Model:

```
function get_name() {
    $this->db->select('first_name');
    $this->db->where('email', $this->session->userdata('email'));
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and this is my controller method:

```
function show_name() {
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $this->users_model->get_name();
    }
```

and the method that passes a name to view:

```
function profile(){
    $data['first_name'] = $this->show_name();
    $this->load->view('members/template', $data);
}
```

**I get nothing in the view, I checked my query and it works fine. Is there anything I'm missing?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update your code. You need to return `first_name` from the function `get_name`

```
function get_name() {
        $this->db->select('first_name');
        $this->db->where('email', $this->session->userdata('email'));
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->row()->first_name;
        }
    }
```

You also need to `return` the value from function `show_name`

```
function show_name() {
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    return $this->users_model->get_name();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this
Controller

```
function profile(){
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $name = $this->users_model->get_name();
    if ($name){
      $data['first_name'] = $name;
      $this->load->view('members/template', $data);
    }else{
      ehco "No User Exist";
      exit;
    }
}
```

Model

```
function get_name() {
        $return =false;
        $this->db->select('first_name');
        $this->db->where('email', $this->session->userdata('email'));
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            $return = $query->row()->first_name;
        }
        return $return ;
    }
```